# How to create dynamic category drop menu in Zend 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am new to zend 2 and trying to generate custom dynamic category menu in top navigation.

For category I am maintaining a table from where it will load the category in the menu . I searched in google but did not get solution which may full fill my purpose. If anybody has a solution please help me.

For reference I have uploaded the image where i need to show the categories and child categories.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To create ZF2 navigation from your database you will need to create a Navigation Factory and add the pages by overriding the `getPages()` method, see below.

```
use Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory;

class MainNavigationFactory extends DefaultNavigationFactory
{

    public function getPages(ContainerInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $categories = // get navigation categories from database

        $configuration = $serviceLocator->get('config'); // get config

        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $configuration['navigation'][$this->getName()][] = $category; // add category to navigation config
        }

        if (isset($configuration['navigation'][$this->getName()])) { // should always be true
            $pages = $this->getPagesFromConfig($configuration['navigation'][$this->getName()]);
            $this->pages = $this->preparePages($serviceLocator, $pages);
        }

        return $this->pages;
    }

}
```

Then you need to register the above factory in you module.config.php.

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'navigation' => 'Application\Navigation\Service\MainNavigationFactory', // you may need to change this path according to your application
    ),
),
```

Finally in your layout you will need to render your navigation with

```
<?php echo $this->navigation('navigation')->menu(); ?>
```

You may need to use a partial view in the [navigation viewhelper](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.navigation.view.helper.menu.html) to achieve the desired layout of the menu as per your picture.

Please note this is only a basic implementation but it should push you in the right direction.